# PORQUE O BROWSER FECHA NO FINAL ? COMO EVITAR

Tags: python, funções

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

#navegador = webdriver.Chrome()

import requests

 

def executaruol():   
    navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
    navegador.get("https://www.uol.com.br")
    
    
executaruol()
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O Selenium fecha porque está dentro de uma função. Quando a função termina de executar o garbage collector do Python fecha o browser. Esse código sem a declaração de função deve dar o comportamento que você espera:

```
from selenium import webdriver

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://www.uol.com.br")
```

Comment: porém vou colocar isto em um botão, então neste caso estou usando como função mas preciso que fique aberto mas ainda não resolvi este desafio.